# How to load json foriegn key data to jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

```
This is how my JSON data is getting using the url.
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "fullName": "Menushi",
    "email": "menushi@gmail.com",
    "contact": "04567383",
    "department": {
        "id": 1,
        "departmentName": "Computing and Information System(CIS)",
        "description": "This department is regarding computer science ",
        "active": true
    },
    "imageUrl": "LCR438D8E9C68",
    "active": true,
    "file": null,
    "address": "Polonnaruwa"
},
```

I want to display the department name in the Jsondata table.Below shows the part of the javascript file.Department object is in onetoone relationship.I want to display department object data also in the table.

```
  $table.DataTable({

        pageLength: 5,
        lengthMenu: [[3, 5, 10, -1], ["3 Records", "5 Records", "10 Records", "All"]],
        ajax: {
            url: jsonUrl,
            dataSrc: ''
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data : 'imageUrl',
                mRender : function(data,type,row){
                    return '<img src="'+window.root+'/resources/images/'+data+'.jpg" class="dataTableImg">';
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'fullName'
            },
            {
                data: 'address'
            },
            {
                data: 'email'

            },
            {
                data: 'department.departmentName',

            },
            {
                data: 'contact'

            }
```

I have used the above way to display the department name in my javascript file..But it display nothing.How I can over come this issue?

Comment: it looks like your object is in an array...show more code from you bottom snippet...your javascript file

Comment: Can you add your library and whole code snippet